# how to set alarm in android programatically?

Tags: android

I'm working on a project in which I want to use alarmManager for setting alarm I'm using this code:

```
    package com.example.alarmdemo;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        // Put here YOUR code.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}



package com.example.alarmdemo;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

   @Override        
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
    08-17 06:48:10.299: D/AndroidRuntime(9864): Shutting down VM
08-17 06:48:10.299: W/dalvikvm(9864): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c08a68)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alarmdemo/com.example.alarmdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.alarmdemo.MainActivity
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.alarmdemo.MainActivity
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
08-17 06:48:10.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9864):     ... 11 more
```

but it is giving exception in activity thread.Can anyone here help me in detecting and correcting my mistake?

Comment: can you post your stacktrace (logcat)

Comment: idk how to post it cz I'm new here

Comment: Edit your answer and post at the end.

Comment: which activity do you want to launch first  (In your androidmanifest.xml file you mentioned .MainActivity) but the java class can't able to find in your project

Comment: oh yes. Got it vinay thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not alarm. You are launching some activity from somewhere in program but it seems like its not registered properly.